# Best way to grep substring from a string before a character or string in golang

Tags: go

I got net.Conn.RemoteAddr() as this:

```
192.168.16.96:64840
```

I only need  IP address without port number

```
...
str := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
strSlice := strings.Split(str, ":")
ipAddress := strSlice[0]
...
```

Is there any simple way?

Comment: Simpler than 3 line?

Comment: ipAddress := strings.Split(conn.Remoteddr().String(), ":")[0]

Comment: @GarMan It still looks ugly.... :( Do I have to wrap these things by my self?

Comment: on a side note: OPs and GarMans code wouldn't work with IPv6

Comment: @DanieleD So, if we get IPv6, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `net.SplitHostPort`, like so

```
ip, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(conn.RemoteAddr().String())
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(ip)
```

Try it on the <kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/V7MHvCURIK)</kbd>

To answer OP's question in the comments above, `net.SplitHostPort` already deals with IPv6.  Given the string

```
net.SplitHostPort("[2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370]:7334")
```

Will work as intended.